# Getting a PS New-Object 80070005 Access is denied error in a PS script - can't run from task scheduler

Tags: excel, powershell, permissions, scheduled-tasks

I have a batch file that runs a PS1 script. I've done this way so I can log error output to a file otherwise I was seeing nothing helpful.

The PS1 script creates an Excel instance, opens up a workbook, runs a macro which itself refreshes a data query, builds and saves a couple of output files. This works no problems at the command line or at the powershell command line.

I have a task in task scheduler launching this batch file to run the exactly same powershell script with the same user credentials (my network username and password).

My error file has this at the top:

```
New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

I have looked for similar problem but can't find anything similar.

I'm trying to understand why this simply doesn't do the same thing as running at the command line.

I think this is a permission problem but where do I start looking?

PS 5.1 (and I've tried under 7.3 no change)

Comment: Try running PS script by right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: Duplicate? [Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed while configure exe in task scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30117146/1701026)

Comment: Finally worked out that changing security from "Run whether the user is logged on or not" to just "Run only when the user is logged on" fixed the problem.